# How does auto play work?

Tags: injustice-2-mobile

When fighting an opponent you have the option to enable auto play. If you enable it from the start does it work by selecting the team with the highest value to win or is there some other criteria?

Basically how does it work?

Comment: Since asking I've found out that it doesn't just work on a teams threat level as I've been beat by teams with a lower threat level.